# Condense AND clause Oracle sql

Tags: oracle, in-clause

I've come across this in one of the sql scripts we have for one of our apps. I notice that it's used in various other places, but isn't it just checking for an existence of an item?

```
AND INSTR((SELECT (',' || REPLACE('OWN, JO', ' ', NULL) || ',') b FROM DUAL),
         (',' || aao.AcctRoleCd || ',')) > 0
```

Where it's looking to see if `'OWN'` or `'JO'` is in `aao.AcctRoleCd`. If it is then `INSTR` would result in its index in the string, so it'll be greater than one. So the `AND` clause would be `true`.

Isn't this poor to check if an item exists like this? Would something more of the lines of an `IN` clause be better?

```
AND aao.AcctRoleCd IN ('OWN', 'JO');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost:

- `'OWN, JO'` is a text literal.
- `REPLACE('OWN, JO', ' ', NULL)` just strips the space from the string giving `'OWN,JO'`.
- `',' || 'OWN,JO' || ','` just concatenates commas to the start and end of the string giving `',OWN,JO,'`.
- `(SELECT ',OWN,JO,') b FROM DUAL)` is redundant and you can just use the previous text literal.
- `INSTR( ',OWN,JO,', (',' || aao.AcctRoleCd || ',') ) > 0` is looking for a comma at the start and end of the substring which equals `aao.AcctRoleCd` so could match either `'OWN'`, `'JO'` or `'OWN,JO'`.

So you can replace it with:

```
AND aao.AcctRoleCd IN ( 'OWN', 'JO', 'OWN,JO' )
```

Now, it may be that `'OWN,JO'` is not a match you are expecting (or may not even be a valid value) and you can strip it from the list but that is something you will need to determine.

Comment: Yup, in this case `'OWN,JO'` can be removed as `aao.AcctRoleCd` can only have one value. It has to be either `'OWN'` or `'JO'`, or some other codes, but only one is valid. So I guess it is safe to replace it with an `IN` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, but thanks for sharing that surprisingly bad code.

```
(SELECT (',' || REPLACE('OWN, JO', ' ', NULL) || ',') b FROM DUAL)
```

is a completely unnecessary scalar subquery. It could be replaced by

```
',' || REPLACE('OWN, JO', ' ', NULL) || ','
```

However, since that snippet has only literals then it could be further replaced by the result:

```
,OWN,JO,
```

and yes, it would seem that whole INSTR could be replaced by the code you suggest, unless aao.AcctRoleCd could contain 'N,J' or some such in which case the original code and your code would get different results. I seriously doubt that is a problem.

Best regards, Stew

Comment: Thanks, in my case, the `'OWN'` and `'JO'` are passed in as a parameter query, but I was just using `'OWN'` and `'JO'` as an example.

Comment: This is technically incorrect as `aao.AcctRoleCd IN ( 'OWN', 'JO')` is not the same as the OP's original code which can match 3 values (`'OWN'`, `'JO'` and `'OWN,JO'`). However, it may be sufficiently close if there are restrictions on the `aao.AcctRoleCd` column that prevents commas in the string (or some other similar restriction) that it could be considered sufficient.